# Why is AIC from multinom and corresponding glm different?

Tags: r, aic

I'm reading the example of the book: "S-PLUS (and R) Manual to Accompany Agresti’s Categorical Data Analysis (2002) 2nd edition " (page 55) and when I try to reproduce the example I get this:

```
snoring<-c(0,2,4,5) 

logit.irls<-glm(cbind(yes=c(24,35,21,30), no=c(1355,603,192,224))~snoring, 
family=binomial(link=logit)) 

summary(logit.irls)

Null deviance: 65.9045  on 3  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  2.8089  on 2  degrees of freedom
**AIC: 27.061**
```

Ok, I get a Akaike information criterion of 27.061.

But when I use the multinorm function from the "nnet" library I get this:

```
modLogit = multinom(cbind(c(24,35,21,30),c(1355,603,192,224))~snoring)

summary(modLogit)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)    snoring
2    3.866248 -0.3973366

Std. Errors:
  (Intercept)    snoring
2   0.1662144 0.05001066

Residual Deviance: 837.7316 
**AIC: 841.7316**
```

Why the AIC (and the Residual Deviance) are too big?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the minus-log-likelihood function is really only defined up to an additive constant and the absolute values of AIC and residual deviance depend on this constant. Hence, for different implementations you can, in general, expect different choices of constant. Hopefully, the *difference* in AIC (or the *difference* in the residual deviance) between two models is the same whether you use `multinom` or `glm`.

N.B. In `multinom` the residual deviance and AIC are computed based on the minus-log-likelihood of independent observations of 0-1-variables, thus 
$$l = - \sum_{i} y_i \log \hat{\pi}_i + (1-y_i) \log(1-\hat{\pi}_i)$$
and AIC$= 2l + 2p$. This is the case even when the data are given in tabulated form. For the AIC computation in `glm` the minus-log-likelihood is based on independent observations of binomial variables, thus 
$$l = - \sum_{k} n_{k1} \log(\hat{\pi}_k) + (n_k - n_{k1}) \log(1-\hat{\pi}_k) + \log {n_k \choose n_{1k}}.$$
When data are in tabulated form as in the question, the difference between the two reported AIC's is precisely twice the sum of the log of the binomial coefficients.

Comment: That's mean the log-likelihood of the multinom have to be computed with another function?

Comment: @Galled, question not really understood. Both R functions compute valid residual deviances and AICs, but the absolute values can not be compared between the functions. This is a matter that one should always be careful about. AIC is only defined up to an additive constant and if you compare two models in terms of AIC you better make sure that you use the same constant (in technical terms, the same reference measure).

Comment: What I meant is that if I could use both AIC to check the fit of a binomial (or multinomial of a responding variable of two choices) model. In any case, how could sure use the same constant, for example if I want to compare the fit of a multinomial model with a log-linear model? ¿Can I use the AIC from multinom?

Comment: I would say that unless you know precisely what is computed you should not expect to be able to compare AIC, say, from two different implementations in two different packages in R.